# Unique Sweat dish recipe required for GOLAB JAMBO

Tags: flavor, organization, tasting

This is a Indian Sweat dish, there are many recipes on the internet. I need to know how would you prepare it, what would you add to make it taste unique?

What will you do, to add a unique flavor to it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is called GULAB JAMUN...

Unique is the wrong word here, If I tell you what I do to make them unique, then it will not be unique anyway...

There are several ways of differentiating your dish - texture, flavor, presentation. You should experiment with these and see what is pleasing to your palette.

A standard variation of Gulab Jamun is call Kala Jamun, where you overheat the balls to make them appear almost black. You should try it. I personally prefer Kala Jamun more than Gulab Jamun...

Comment: +1 for not calling them an idiot for calling it golab jambo.  Also I'm going to have to try this caramelized version next time I make gulab jamun